# What exactly am I looking at in my online hosted SharePoint site?

Tags: web-services

I am completely new to SharePoint and as part of a college project I have to develop an application using it.

I have hosted the site online at: http://www.blacknight.com/sharepoint.html 
The bronze plan.

When i log into the site through my hosting service see the home tab on the top left and one the says "Site actions" on the top right.  Could some one tell me what it is that I am looking at? Is this just a homepage? and can I make changes to the site, like adding a web part from here??

I have yet to get foundation working on my laptop so I dont know anything about it. When I do get foundation do i log onto the site through it and edit the site that way?? I have no idea how it will work.

Any help would be really appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The site actions menu is available on any page to any user who has an edit right in the site.

Looks like that provider has given you a SharePoint 2007 instance, in 2010 the Site Actions menu is in the upper left.

If you can put the page into edit mode then you can add web parts, provided there are web part zones.

Site Actions > Edit Page > Add a Web Part